# Linear Algebra: coordinates and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I'm asked to show that if $f,g \in \mathrm{Sig}_3$ (sig stands for signal) have the coordinates $x,y \in \mathbb{R^4}$ with respect to the basis $(v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3)$, then 
$$\left<f,g\right>=\pi(x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3+x_4y_4)$$
where
$$v_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 
v_1=\cos x,
v_2=\cos(2x),
v_3=\cos(3x)$$
and
$$C^0([0;2\pi])$$

Any idea how to show this? I'm completely stuck. All of the examples online use vectors with numbers, but I'm just given functions.

Comment: Not well formatted... Better read and study this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What's missing is the definition of $\left<f,g\right>$.

Comment: <f,g> is the integral from 0 to 2Pi of f(x)*g(x) dx

Comment: HELP WOULD GREATLY BE APPRECIATED.

Comment: Shouting does not earn help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f=[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4]$ and $g=[b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4]$, you'll have $$f(x)=a_1\frac1{\sqrt2}+a_2\cos x+a_3\cos (2x)+a_4\cos (3x)\\g(x)=b_1\frac1{\sqrt2}+b_2\cos x+b_3\cos (2x)+b_4\cos (3x)$$
The inner product $\left<f,g\right>$ would be
$$\left<f,g\right>=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x$$ Before we begin integrating it's worth noting that for every distinct $m,n \in\Bbb{Z}$ and $m,n\geq0$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(mx)\cos(nx)\mathrm{d}x&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\cos((m+n)x)+\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\cos((m-n)x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=0+0\\&=0
\end{align}
$$
(Note that the RHS integrals are on a whole period of $\cos({kx})$ where $k\in\Bbb{N}$, so they equal zero.)

Going back to the inner product, now we know that the integrals $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos x\mathrm{d}x$, $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(2x)\mathrm{d}x$, $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(3x)\mathrm{d}x$, $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos x\cos(2x)\mathrm{d}x$, $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos x\cos(3x)\mathrm{d}x$, and $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(2x)\cos(3x)\mathrm{d}x$ are zero, so we can omit them from the multiplication result. What remains is
$$
\begin{align}
\left<f,g\right>&=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(a_1b_1\frac12+a_2b_2\cos^2x+a_3b_3\cos^2(2x)+a_4b_4\cos^2(3x)\right)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$

but since for $k\in\Bbb{Z}$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(kx)\mathrm{d}x&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac12+\frac12 \cos(2kx)\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\pi+0\\&=\pi
\end{align}
$$

we'll have
$$
\begin{align}
\left<f,g\right>&=a_1b_1\pi+a_2b_2\pi+a_3b_3\pi+a_4b_4\pi\\
&=\pi(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3+a_4b_4)
\end{align}
$$
which is what you want.

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit hard to understand because it's written in a weird order.  Usually the question goes (*environment*) (*specifics*) (*statement to be proved*).  If I understand your problem well, I think it would be better written this way:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be elements of $\mathrm{Sig}_3$, which has inner product
>   $$
>     \left<f,g\right> = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g(x)\,dx
> $$
>   [I don't actually know what $\mathrm{Sig}_3$ is, even with the information that Sig stands for signal.  But I'm trying to work from the context.]  Let
>   \begin{align*}
>    v_0 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
>    v_1 &= \cos(x) \\
>    v_2 &= \cos(2x) \\
>    v_3 &= \cos(3x)
> \end{align*}
>   Suppose that with respect to the basis $(v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3)$, $f$ and $g$ have coordinates $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  Show that
>   $$
>     \left<f,g\right> = \pi(x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 + x_3 y_3 + x_4 y_4)
> $$

Please correct me if that's not what your problem is.  But notice how it starts with the environment of the vector space $\mathrm{Sig}_3$, along the definition of the inner product.  Then comes the specific information: for these two elements, we have these two coordinate vectors.  Finally, the statement we are to prove.

So I think you will be home free if you understand the meaning of this sentence:

> Suppose that with respect to the basis $(v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3)$, $f$ and $g$ have coordinates $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

What does this tell you about the formulas for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?  Once you know this, you should be able to compute $\left<f,g\right>$ directly.

Comment: Sorry about that, my native language is not English. It's my first time using this site and I'm trying to translate the question into English. I'm only using this site, because I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out. I have absolute no idea what to do. I really appreciate you trying to help, but I still have no clue.

Comment: That's OK, we all start somewhere. :-) So does the word *basis* in the context of vector spaces really not have any meaning to you?  If so, I could solve the problem for you, but you will be just as confused with the next problem.

Comment: I've honestly been neglecting this class due the holidays, I'm hopeless when it comes to linear algebra

Comment: Do you have a textbook?  Look up the word basis.  Do you have a teacher?  Ask them.  Because I think you need more help than you can get here.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that. Thanks for the advice.